# Asking for a sequence of inputs from user python3

Tags: python, loops, python-3.6

I am working on a python exercise asking for 
Write Python programs that read a sequence of integer inputs and print

```
The smallest and largest of the inputs.
```

My code so far

```
def smallAndLarge():

    num1 = int(input("Enter a number: "))
    num2 = int(input("Enter a number: "))

    if num1 > num2:
        print(num1,"is the largest number, while",num2,"is the smallest number.")
    else:
        print(num2,"is the largest number, while",num1,"is the smallest number.")


smallAndLarge()
```

I am using def smallAndlarge(): since my instructor wants us to use a def function for all of our programs in the future.

My question is how do I ask for multiple inputs from a user until they decided they dont want to add anymore inputs. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Read about `while` loops: https://wiki.python.org/moin/WhileLoop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could let the user flag when they are finished. ([live example](https://repl.it/LfcN))

```
numbers = [];
in_num = None

while (in_num != ""):
    in_num = input("Please enter a number (leave blank to finish): ")
    try:
        numbers.append(int(in_num))
    except:
        if in_num != "":
            print(in_num + " is not a number. Try again.")

# Calculate largest and smallest here.
```

You can choose any string you want for the "stop", as long as it's not the same as the initial value of `in_num`.

As an aside, you should add logic to handle bad input (i.e. not an integer) to avoid runtime exceptions.

In this specific example, you'd also probably want to create `smallest` and `largest` variables, and calculate their values after each input. Doesn't matter so much for a small calculation, but as you move to bigger projects, you'll want to keep the efficiency of the code in mind.

Comment: Thank you mac, That helped a lot! I appreciate your help.

Comment: @Matticus you bet!