# How can I run a same function multiple times, parallel in python?

Tags: python-3.x, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I have a program where there is one function. The basic moto of the code is asking the user if he wants to keep adding values or stop. If yes, The function where the value is asked to be added would be called multiple times, that also in parallel, so execution will also be parallel. in a pseudocode way,

```
def func1():
a = input("Enter value" )
do something with a

b = input("would you like to add more values?" )
if b == "Y"
func1()
else
exit()
```

But this is not parallel. It will wait for the first function to end completely. I know I have to use multiprocessing here. But how to solve the exact problem, I can't figure out. Thanks for any help ...

Comment: How do you expect your user to respond in parallel?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Asking for a sequence of inputs from user python3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46436223/asking-for-a-sequence-of-inputs-from-user-python3)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you really need to use multiprocessing here, you could do this in a basic while loop like:

```py
value = 0

while True:
    a = input("Enter value: ")
    value += int(a)

    b = input("would you like to add more values? ")
    if b == "Y" or b == "y":
        pass
    else:
        break

print("The value: " + str(value))
```

Then the program would work like that:

```sh
$ python test.py
Enter value: 345673
would you like to add more values? y
Enter value: 43563
would you like to add more values? y
Enter value: 546734
would you like to add more values? n
The value: 935970
```